# python save url list in txt file

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to make a python function to save a list of URLs in .txt file

Example: visit http://forum.domain.com/ and save all `viewtopic.php?t=` word URL in .txt file

```
http://forum.domain.com/viewtopic.php?t=1333
http://forum.domain.com/viewtopic.php?t=2333
```

I use this function but not save
I am very new in python can someone help me to create this

```
web_obj = opener.open('http://forum.domain.com/')
data = web_obj.read()

fl_url_list = open('urllist.txt', 'r')
url_arr = fl_url_list.readlines()
fl_url_list.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is far from trivial and can have quite a few corner cases (I suppose the page you're referring to is a web page)

To give you a few pointers, you need to:

- download the web page : you're already doing it (in `data`)
- extract the URLs : this is hard, most probably, you'll want to usae an html parser, extract `<a>` tags, fetch the `href`attribute and put that into a list. then filter that list to have only the url formatted like you like (say with viewtopic). Let's say you got it into urlList
- then open a file for Writing Text (thus `wt`, not `r`).
- write the content `f.write('\n'.join(urlList))`
- close the file

I advise to try to follow these steps and ask relevant questions when you're stuck on a particular issue.